# Is PHP removing CR when reading text file?

Tags: php, text, text-processing, carriage-return, file-read

A certain txt file contains only CRLF line breaks. It have been confirmed by opening the file in Notepad++ with "Show All Characters" enabled.

When reading the file with PHP, using file_get_contents(), or fopen(), the CR characters seems to be filtered out:

```
<?php
    ...
    $fh = fopen($path, 'r');

    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $string .= fread($fh, 1024);
    }

    preg_match_all('/\r/', $string, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);

    // 0 matches: array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }

    $string2 = file_get_contents($path);
    preg_match_all('/\r/', $string2, $matches2);
    var_dump($matches2);

    // 0 matches: array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }
?>
```

I am confused, because each mentioned function's documentation says nothing about this. Maybe there are other methods to open files in the exact they are stored.

Need confirmation about if these functions does filter out or "normalize" the CR characters. Is so, what else these functions might be "normalizing"? Is there a method to avoid that behaviour?

To be more explicit I need these CR characters and every bit to remain intact when I load the file into my variable.

Thank you

Comment: Try `"\\r"` instead of `'\r'`.

Comment: Tryed, "/\\r/" but still the same.

Comment: EOL is different in windows and unix. If you read windows text file by your code \r will be found. If unix one - not. It writes only NL character

Comment: @splash58 i know that, but what if the file has a signature over its exact binary content? There should be a way in PHP to load the CR characters same as every byte and bit from any given file. Is there any parameter or function to achieve that?

Comment: No info in the file what a linebreak is used. Better say for what purpose you want it.

Comment: It is for parsing the exact binary content of the file. The file contains only CRLF type linebreaks

Comment: $string = str_replace("\r",'', $string),  If \r no in text, string will not changed  Then use only \n as line break.

Comment: The point is to keep the content intact, not to change it, what happens if the file is produced by third party? you cannot control which line breaks they are using. str_replace wont replace \r characters because apparently they have disappeared with no explicit consent, and that is the problem, i don't know in which part of my code the CR characters got filtered out, and thats the reason i have not been able to preserve them. I want these CR characters in my variable.

Comment: @Imikl took your code add line `echo strpos($string, "\r");` and test files with CR. They was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what *fopen* does depending on the parameters you give, and you can find it in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

> Windows offers a text-mode translation flag ('t') which will
>   transparently translate \n to \r\n when working with the file. In
>   contrast, you can also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will not
>   translate your data. To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as
>   the last character of the mode parameter.

i.e. you can avoid such "translation" by using the 'b' flag in the *mode* parameter. For example:

```
fopen($path, 'rb'); // Read in binary mode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
preg_match_all('/'.PHP_EOL.'/', $string, $matches);
```

**PHP_EOL** is as the newline character in a cross-platform way, so it handles Windows/Mac/Unix.

Also check [documentation](https://php.net/manual/pl/reserved.constants.php) for this constant.

Comment: So is PHP "normalizing" or giving treatment to the content when loading files? is it possible to avoid that behaviour?

Comment: I think you should be able to open files in binary mode with `open($file, 'rb')`. Then PHP will not replace newline characters.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel you are correct but just a little detail, `open` is misspelled, it is `fopen`. I didn't notice it because I didn't know `open` function did not exist.